# Eigen behavior when casting to the same underlying type

Tags: c++, casting, eigen3

I have a template class, `MyClass<...>`, which has member variables of type `Eigen::Matrix<X, N, M>` where `X` is the native template parameter for a particular instance of `MyClass`.

Assuming that my *private* variable of the aforementioned type is `myVar`. In order to make the `setMyVar` function generic, I define it as a template function like

```
  template <typename U>
  void setMyVar(const Eigen::Matrix<U, 3, 1>& newVal) const { 
     // myVar is of type Eigen::Matrix<T, 3, 1>
     myVar = newVal.cast<T>();
  }
```

My question is whether Eigen skips the casting operation in case `T == U`.

I am in particular interested in learning the behavior of Eigen in such a scenario. Otherwise I am very well aware of alternative solutions such as using SFINAE to force to compiler to choose among the right overloads of `setMyVar` or use `if constexp (std::is_same_v<T, U) {...} else {...}` *(for c++17)* to decide whether a cast is required or not during compile time.

Thanks

Comment: What is T? A template variable? I can't see typename T.

Comment: If `U` and `T` are the same, `cast` is a NOP (i.e., just returns a reference to the original object).

Comment: @MFnx In case the matrix ```myVar``` is large, one would want to avoid casting due to the obvious reason that it will cause unnecessary extra burden to the cpu. Answer to your question is, I would expect ```cast``` to return ```newVal``` as is. You can assume ```T``` to be of floating point type.

Comment: @chtz, is it possible to point to the source code that handles this case?

Comment: @ozlsn if you have performance concerns, benchmark your code (with optimisation enabled). Any blind assumptions without mesurenment are futile.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand the question, you are asking if there are 2 copies or just one, or more clearly if there is an intermediate matrix. Even in the case of the cast, I do hope there isn't, that's the whole point of expression templates.

Comment: It is a bit scattered in the source. Maybe the important part is here: https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/8071cda5714d7f/Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h#lines-514

Comment: Hmm. I assume the line which writes ```typedef typename conditional<is_same<CurrentScalarType,NewScalarType>::value,
                              const XprType&,CastType>::type type;``` unveils the intend by setting the return type as ```XprType``` if input and output scalar types are the same. Thanks @chtz

Comment: @ozlsn if you find a good answer and want to help future readers, you are welcome to write an answer to your own question